Where can I find orientation of space probes as a function of time?
Ephemerides for many space probes can be obtained from JPL Horizons using their API or their web app. But this only includes data on positions of the probes, velocities etc., but not their orientation in space. Any orientation-related data items like e.g. "17. North Pole position angle & distance" just yield "n.a." instead of useful data.
Is there any source that I can query to get the orientation or the probe I'm interested in as a function of time?

For deep space probes I’d imagine that their orientation would have to be “antenna towards Earth” most of the time, but otherwise specifying a reference frame/coordinate system for that rotation might also be difficult.

@controlgroup for the complete orientation we also need a roll angle, which the "antenna towards Earth" lacks.

That info might be available via the SPICE toolkit https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/naif/tutorials.html This looks promising: 20 ck "The subsystem (C-matrix Kernel) that deals with orientation of spacecraft and rotating structures on the spacecraft"

There are some clips of some animations of this in What is this block of long, skinny rectangles in this New Horizons trajectory/operations simulation?

@PM2Ring Got it exactly right. C-matrix Kernels do exist for some spacecraft and some solar system bodies; JPL's Horizons system does not provide that information but it does occasionally use that information. JPL's SPICE software package is what uses those kernels. Whether you can find CK kernels is a different question. It's important to remember that while space probes as a general rule do not know where they are in space, they do know how they are oriented in space and their guidance, navigation and control systems work to keep that orientation to something commanded by people on Earth.

As @DavidHammen states, you need the SPICE toolkit along with C-kernels to evaluate orientation.  SPICE data for various missions can be found in link.  Taking Deep Impact for example, the C-kernels are stored in link.  The ckinfo.txt file there describes the kernels and what must be done.  Evidently you must write your own program to access and display the data.

I think want you want are the ck ("Camera"-matrix Kernel) kernels and to use SPICE instead (brief intro here) instead. (Horizons uses the SPK parts of SPICE for producing positions but since you're more interested in the spacecraft aspects, I think you need the rest of SPICE)
